# Как использовать объекты первой формы во второй? Lazarus

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

Например, я кладу Button1 на Form2. Button1 при нажатии должен произвести действия с Edit1.Text, который расположен на Form1.

Comment: Задача решается, но архитектура очень странная. Лезть к контролам другой формы не очень хорошо. Что Вы пытаетесь сделать

Comment: именно то, что написала. Мне нужно, при нажатии на кнопку во второй форме, получить данные из Edit1.Text, расположенном на Form1, и проделать с этими данными действия.

Comment: Когда кому-то нужен Ваш паспорт, он не вламывается к Вам в квартиру. Он просит Вас принести его самостоятельно. А после работы с паспортом отдает обратно Вам же

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не до архитектуры. Тут бы вопрос внятно задать.

Answer (score 1):

По-простому задачу можно решить так:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := Form1.Edit1.Text; 
end;
```

Вы обращаетесь, таким образом, напрямую к Edit1, который находится на Form1. Разумеется, модуль, где описана Form1 (например, Unit1), должен быть прописан в Uses в модуле Form2:

```
Uses Form1;
```

Это - плохой подход, как вам выше отметили в комментариях: во-первых, напрямую обращаться к компонентам одной формы из другой формы - моветон. Во-вторых, с таким подходом вы рискуете нарваться на перекрестное использование Uses, а это запрещено.

Более правилен другой подход: вы объявляете переменную вне форм

```
var
  MyString: string;
```

, значение которой присваиваете при изменении Edit1.Text, например, по событию EditingDone, которое возникает после того, как пользователь поменял Edit1.Text:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1EditingDone(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyString := TEdit(Sender).Text;
end;
```

Теперь при нажатии на кнопку на второй форме уже будет выполняться код:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := MyString; 
end;
```

Это более правильный подход.

Comment: Этот подход более неправилен, чем плохой, но хотя бы прямой и открытый, первый неправильный подход. Тот, значит, "моветон", а этот - элегантный?

Comment: @Igor Я пока не вижу вашего, правильного-элегантного ответа. "Чужого клеща всякий облаять норовит" (с) Марк Твен :)

Comment: "Мой брат может швырнуть твоего через забор."